# Identity element of matrix group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we have the following:
$$G=\Bigg\{ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     \overline{a} & \overline{b} \\
     \overline{0} & \overline{c}
  \end{array} \right] \Bigg|\overline{a},\overline{c} \in \mathbb{F}_3^* \text{ and } \overline{b} \in \mathbb{F}_3 \Bigg\}
$$

$$H=\Bigg\{ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     \overline{0} & \overline{b} \\
     \overline{c} & \overline{0}
  \end{array} \right] \Bigg| \overline{b},\overline{c} \in \mathbb{F}_3^* \Bigg\}
$$.

$G$ is obviously a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ and the identity element is $ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     \overline{1} & \overline{0} \\
     \overline{0} & \overline{1}
  \end{array} \right]$.

My question is: is $H$ a group? Since $b,c \in \mathbb{F}_3^*=\{\overline{1},\overline{2}\}$, the identity matrix of $2 \times 2$-matrices isn't an element of $H$ because $b$ and $c$ can't equal $\overline{0}$ and the other coefficients are always $\overline{0}$ and thus can't equal $\overline{1}$. So is there some other identity for $H$? Or is it impossible for $H$ to be a group because of this?

Also, for all $GL_n(F)$ the identity element is just the $n \times n$ identity matrix, right? I'm a little thrown off by the integers modulo $n$ thing because some matrix coefficients can come from a group under addition and others from a group under multiplication.

Comment: $H$ is not even closed, as $A := \pmatrix{1&0\\1&1} \in H$ but $A^3 = I \not\in H$.

Comment: Typo in your description of $H$?

Comment: Indeed, $H$ as described is not a group

Comment: I just made up some $H$ without checking if it's closed under multiplication and inverses. I've edited $H$ now so that it's closed.

Comment: So if I understand correctly $H$ is still not a group because it doesn't have an identity element?

Answer (score 1):

in a group, the  identity element is unique, and for every element
$x$ the inverse  $x^{-1}$ of $x$ also is unique.

As $H$ does not
contain the identity element $I_2$,  it is not a subgroup of $GL_2
(F_3)$. Clearly  $I_n$ is the neutral element of $GL_n (F)$ and is
unique.